# How to generate code from LLVM which is then I want to given as the input to the Z3 prover

Tags: clang, llvm, z3, clang++, llvm-ir

I have to generate an intermediate code from LLVM and I have to given that as the input to the Z3 prover. Is it possible?

Comment: HI, welcome to SO, it is important to provide well documented questions, in this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you can find some keys for it

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but not for the faint-hearted. See http://rightingcode.org/tutorials/popl20/index.html for one possible approach.